# htaccess rewrite/redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I am having some problems constructing a rewrite rule. The url I want to rewrite and ultimately redirect has a search query in it and looks like this:

`http://www.mysite.com/pages.php?category=fruit`

I would like to redirect it to:

`http://www.mysite.com/pages.php/fruit`

The original address does NOT exist any more. I have tried to construct a rewrite but this is not quite working how I want it to work

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =category=fruit` 
RewriteRule ^pages\.php$ pages.php/fruit/ [L,R=301]
```

goes to

```
http://www.mysite.com/home/linux123/m/mysite.com/user/htdocs/pages.php/fruit/
```

Any advice on fixing the construction of the rewrite rule would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't even need htaccess. Just use $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"] instead of $_GET['category']. Just note that path_info starts with a '/' so you should remove that substr($_SERVER["PATH_INFO"], 1)

Comment: thanks Gerben. I realised that I could get the data and/or redirect from the page itself after I gave it a few hours to cogitate over.

Answer (score 2):

The way URL rewriting works is that it takes non-existant URL and rewrites it to point to the one that exists. The non-existant URL is more of presentation thing rather than a functional thing. You are doing it the other way round, the links on your web pages should be like `http://www.mysite.com/pages.php/fruit` and when the user clicks on them they should internally be forwarded to something like this `http://www.mysite.com/pages.php?category=fruit`. The rewrite rule has to be written accordingly which would be

```
^pages\.php/([A-Za-z])*$ pages.php?category=$1 [NC,L]
```

if the category is strictly alphabetical otherwise for alphanumeric

```
^pages\.php/([A-Za-z0-9])*$ pages.php?category=$1 [NC,L]
```

You can even test your regex rewrite rules using this online validator;

[Regex Validator](http://tools.netshiftmedia.com/regexlibrary/)

Hope this helps..

Comment: thanks for your advice. However what I want to do is use my new system. The new system does not use a query string. I want to use the non-query url. I also want it to be specific to finite number of urls - i.e. one for fruit, one for vegetables and one for sundries... The main reason for this is that the old urls with the query string are still stuck in google and although I have provided a new sitemap I just want to catch anything that has been indexed with the old query string url and redirect it.

Comment: I guess all I really need to know is how to make it so the rewrite rewrite rule doesn't contain the linux bit: home/linux123/m/mysite.com/user/htdocs

Comment: RewriteRule removes the unix path automatically. You can only match the part after the rewritebase. Easiest way to remove the old urls from google it to just rename pages.php to e.g. pages2.php, and change the htaccess accordingly. If you want the old url to redirect to the new url, you could create a new pages.php file that does something like header("Location: http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/pages2.php/{$_GET['category'}/") or just use htaccess for it. I would also suggest to remove the .php part from the url. So ^pages/([A-Za-z])*$ pages2.php?category=$1 [NC,L]